# How To Hide JButton With Separate Method And Call In a New Class

Tags: java

I know I'm doing something wrong here but I can't figure it what. I want to set the visibility of two JButtons to false with a method, and to true with another method. Then I want to call the methods in another class. What am I doing wrong?

```
private static JButton draw;
private static JButton pick;
private JTextField tf;

public gui() {

    super("title");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());


    draw = new JButton("Draw"); //makes a new button to click.
    draw.addActionListener( //MAKES NEW INNER CLASS TO DEFINE WHAT draw DOES

                new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) { //checks if clicked. 

                        draw.setVisible(false);
                        pick.setVisible(false);
                        cards.select = 0;
                        System.out.println(cards.select);

                    }

                }

            );



    pick = new JButton("Pick"); //makes a new button to click.
    pick.addActionListener( //MAKES NEW INNER CLASS TO DEFINE WHAT pick DOES

                new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) { //checks if clicked. 

                        pick.setVisible(false);
                        draw.setVisible(false);

                        cards.select = 1;
                        System.out.println(cards.select);

                    }

                }

            );

    tf = new JTextField("lol", 20); //sets size and text

    add(tf);
    add(draw);
    add(pick);


}

public static void addDP() {
    pick.setVisible(true);
    draw.setVisible(true);

}

public static void removeDP() {
    pick.setVisible(false);
    draw.setVisible(false); 
}
```

Class calling the method:

```
        gui add = new gui();
        add.addDP();
```

I have a feeling it's something to do with the static method but when I make the method not static it says I can't change the visibility.

Comment: Can you provide us with the caller class too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you remember to call the function to hide the buttons within the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)?

Here's a fully contained working example of me calling a method to hide buttons from another object. Notice that it's done inside the EDT (using SwingUtilities):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class HideButtonGui
{
    private JFrame myFrame;
    private PanelWithButtons comp;

    public HideButtonGui() {
        setupGui();
    }

    private void setupGui() {
        myFrame = new JFrame();
        comp = new PanelWithButtons();

        myFrame.getContentPane().add(comp.getPanel());
        myFrame.setSize(400, 300);
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HideButtonGui gui = new HideButtonGui();
        gui.go();
    }

    public void go() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> myFrame.setVisible(true));

        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);

            /*
                This is me calling a function from another class.
                That function hides the buttons.
                Notice that all interaction with GUI elements is done
                in the Event Dispatch Thread.
            */
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> comp.hideButtons());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


class PanelWithButtons {
    private JButton drawBtn;
    private JButton pickBtn;
    private JPanel myPanel;

    private int count = 0;

    public PanelWithButtons() {
        setupGui();
    }

    private void setupGui() {
        drawBtn = new JButton("Draw");
        pickBtn = new JButton("Pick");

        myPanel = new JPanel();
        myPanel.add(drawBtn);
        myPanel.add(pickBtn);

        drawBtn.addActionListener(evt -> hideButtonClicked());
        pickBtn.addActionListener(evt -> pickButtonClicked());
    }

    private void pickButtonClicked() {
        hideButtons();
        count = 1;
        System.out.println(count);
    }

    private void hideButtonClicked() {
        hideButtons();
        count = 0;
        System.out.println(count);
    }

    public void hideButtons() {
        drawBtn.setVisible(false);
        pickBtn.setVisible(false);
    }

    public void showButtons() {
        drawBtn.setVisible(true);
        pickBtn.setVisible(true);
    }


    public JPanel getPanel() {
        return myPanel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have a new issue now though. In the main method after         HideButtonGui gui = new HideButtonGui();
        gui.go();     -   I wanted to put more code to run but it wouldn't run. Why is that? (sorry I'm new to JFrame)

Comment: I have a whole entire program named "cards" that runs a card game. It defines ints, makes while loops, etc. The reason I am making this GUI is for the card game.